# How can I translate this CSS3 to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}

#share {
    -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}
```

How can I replicate this behavior using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

At least for the second part, you can do:

```
$('#share').css('-webkit-animation', 'spin 10s infinite linear');
```

Comment: To be pedantic, that's jQuery, not exactly Javascript.

Comment: That is jQuery - not Javascript. My guess is that the question is about how to create animations using Javascript instead of CSS transitions and CSS animations.

Comment: @XavierHo Yes, you're right. I assume everybody uses it (probably a bad habit when answering questions here) because I'm big on it, and I'll be sure to give a javascript answer if Ryan-Ryan doesn't like it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with jQuery. I'm rather surprised you got a downvote.  Gonna put you back to 0. :]

Comment: @XavierHo Thanks. I'm surprised this guy hasn't responded if this is what he was looking for yet.